# Why does vue route not pass props correctly when reloading or using url?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Route:

```
{
    path: '/markets/:code.:exchange',
    name: 'Markets',
    component: Markets,
    props: true
},
```

Right now, it works as intended when I do a router push like so:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'Markets', params: {code: this.model.Code, exchange: this.model.Exchange}})
```

However, when I enter the url, or reload the page, it shows a blank page and this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

For example in the above router push function if I push params: {AAPL, US} it would go to /markets/AAPL.US and correctly pass the props. But if I write the same exact thing in the url and enter, or if I reload the page, nothing shows up, and gives the above error.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you reload a page with props the data in props in lost. Maybe you should consider using state manager like store in your app

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your route, you can't use that dot in the path.. you have to use a slash:

```
{
  path: '/markets/:code/:exchange',
  name: 'Markets',
  component: Markets,
  props: true
},
```

Comment: You have this error only in this route or in all the routes? Using Apache?

Comment: This is the only route that I am passing props to, so yes. No Apache, this is a development build.